# caused error while Importing opcua xml files

Tags: python, python-asyncio, opc-ua

I have created testing_nodeset2.xml using siemens SiOME modelling editor , so first of all i imported opcua device , opcua machinery and opcua pump xml files into editor and then created own namespace using companion specification . finally i exported testing_noeset2.xml file. Now i want to import xml files.

1. is the correct way to create own namespace ?
2. do i need to import all xml files into python code according opcua companion specification ?
   here is the code:

````
import asyncio
async def main():
    server = Server()
    await server.init()     
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://192.168.1.216:4000")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Di.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Machinery.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Pumps.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("testing_Nodeset.xml")
    await server.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())```

here is the error i am getting : 

AddNodesItem: Requested NodeId NodeId(Identifier=3062, NamespaceIndex=0, NodeIdType=<NodeIdType.Numeric: 2>) already exists
failure adding node NodeData(nodeid:NodeId(Identifier=3062, NamespaceIndex=0, NodeIdType=<NodeIdType.Numeric: 2>)) "The requested node id is already used by another node."(BadNodeIdExists)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\thesis\opcua\opc_server\opc_server\nodeset file testing\nodeset.py", line 50, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\thesis\opcua\opc_server\opc_server\nodeset file testing\nodeset.py", line 40, in main
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Nodeset2.xml")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\asyncua\server\server.py", li    node = await self._add_node_data(nodedata, no_namespace_migration=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\asyncua\common\xmlimporter.py", line 228, in _add_node_data
    node = await self.add_object(nodedata, no_namespace_migration)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\asyncua\common\xmlimporter.py", line 349, in add_object
    res[0].StatusCode.check()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\asyncua\ua\uatypes.py", line 328, in check
    raise UaStatusCodeError(self.value)
asyncua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadNodeIdExists: "The requested node id is already used by another node."(BadNodeIdExists)



does anybody has an idea , how can this error be solved? 
your advice and solution would be apreciated.
````

Answer (score 0):

You should not import Opc.Ua.Nodeset2.xml. Because it is already import at the start of the server.

Comment: even though if i do not import opc.ua.Nodeset2.xml , it still occur an error : raise UaError(f"Attribute '{attname}' defined in xml is not found in object '{objclass}'")
asyncua.ua.uaerrors._base.UaError: Attribute 'EncodingMask' defined in xml is not found in object '<class 'PhysicalAddressDataType'>